# In spring tool suite it don't show exception instead it showing a prompts to change prospective(Debug prospective)

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite

When i want to see some exception in sts(Spring tool suite) console its don't show any any exception or error instead it showing a prompt to confirm perspective swith to Debug.
In spring suppose i have a bean and its id="person".
If in test class if i call like this

```
    BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResourse("com/any/yyy/application-context.xml"));
Person person=factory.getBean("perso", Person.class);
```

I intensionally write "perso" instead of "person" to show the exception but it don't show.[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egNBo.jpg)

Comment: So did you click yes to see the debug breakpoint, which your program hit after you started? As the dialog states, your program is suspended at a breakpoint, which is probably before your statement, so the program is not yet at a point where the exception would be thrown.

Comment: Yeah... How can i slove it....?

Comment: Well, continue debugging until the program hits your line. Then you should see the exception.